# Using gRPC calls in a eclipse Plugin development

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, grpc, eclipse-rcp, grpc-java

`enter code here`I try to develop a plugin for eclipse, where it's possible, to communicate via gRPC calls to another application. The Eclipse plugin should act as a client. I use a target platform, to integrate all gRPC dependencies I need for that.

When I try to open a **ManagedChanel**, with the **ManagedChannelBuilder**

```
ManagedChannel channel2 = ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress("localhost", port).usePlaintext().build();
```

it says, that there is no functional chanel builder, but ive added the dependency for it (okhttp). When I open, A **ManagedChanel** manually, with  **OkHttpChannelBuilder** it opens a chanel.

```
channel1 = io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpChannelBuilder.forAddress("localhost", port)
                .nameResolverFactory(new DnsNameResolverProvider())
                .usePlaintext()
                .build();
```

But when I try to execute a Response, with the channel, I get a  "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/grpc/Context"

```
public String stopGDBHost() {
        GDBHostServiceBlockingStub gdbStub = GDBHostServiceGrpc.newBlockingStub(channel1);
                 
        StatusResponse response = gdbStub.stopGDBHost(null);
          
        return response.getErrorMessage();
          
    }
```

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/grpc/Context
    at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl$RealChannel.newCall(ManagedChannelImpl.java:994)
    at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl.newCall(ManagedChannelImpl.java:907)
    at io.grpc.internal.ForwardingManagedChannel.newCall(ForwardingManagedChannel.java:63)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.blockingUnaryCall(ClientCalls.java:150)
```

The Strange thing is the class Context is in the class path, but somehow it still can't be found. Here are my plugin_dependencies.

[enter image description he](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erbZs.png)

Does somebody get gRPC in eclipse plugin development already get to run?  Or does somebodey know how to solfe this ?

Editt: Manifest

```
 Manifest-Version: 1.0
    Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
    Bundle-Name: Test2
    Bundle-SymbolicName: Test2;singleton:=true
    Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
    Require-Bundle: javax.annotation;bundle-version="1.3.5",
     org.eclipse.ui;bundle-version="3.202.0",`enter code here`
     wrapped.io.grpc..grpc-stub;bundle-version="1.55.1",
     wrapped.io.grpc.grpc-okhttp;bundle-version="1.55.1",
     wrapped.io.grpc.grpc-protobuf;bundle-version="1.55.1",
     com.google.guava;bundle-version="31.1.0",
     wrapped.com.google.protobuf.protobuf-java;bundle-version="3.22.3",
     wrapped.io.grpc.grpc-core;bundle-version="1.55.1",
     wrapped.io.grpc.grpc-api;bundle-version="1.55.1",
     wrapped.io.grpc.grpc-context;bundle-version="1.55.1"
    Automatic-Module-Name: Test2
    Bundle-ClassPath: .
    Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-17
    DynamicImport-Package: *
```

Manifest of grpc-core and grpc-context

```
 Manifest-Version: 1.0
    Bnd-LastModified: 1688104218240
    Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
    Bundle-Name: Bundle derived from maven artifact io.grpc:grpc-context:1
     .55.1
    Bundle-SymbolicName: wrapped.io.grpc.grpc-context
    Bundle-Version: 1.55.1
    Created-By: 17.0.7 (Eclipse Adoptium)
    DynamicImport-Package: *
    Export-Package: io.grpc;version="1.55.1"
    Implementation-Title: jar
    Implementation-Version: 1.55.1
    Import-Package: io.grpc.override;resolution:=optional
    Require-Capability: osgi.ee;filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.7))"
    Tool: Bnd-6.4.0.202211291949
```

---

```
 Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bnd-LastModified: 1688104213114
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Bundle derived from maven artifact io.grpc:grpc-core:1.55
 .1
Bundle-SymbolicName: wrapped.io.grpc.grpc-core
Bundle-Version: 1.55.1
Created-By: 17.0.7 (Eclipse Adoptium)
DynamicImport-Package: *
Export-Package: io.grpc.inprocess;version="1.55.1";uses:="io.grpc,io.g
 rpc.internal",io.grpc.internal;version="1.55.1";uses:="com.google.com
 mon.base,com.google.common.util.concurrent,io.grpc,javax.annotation",
 io.grpc.util;version="1.55.1";uses:="io.grpc,io.grpc.internal,javax.a
 nnotation,javax.net.ssl"
Implementation-Title: jar
Implementation-Version: 1.55.1
Import-Package: com.google.common.base;resolution:=optional;version="[
 31.1,32)",com.google.common.collect;resolution:=optional;version="[31
 .1,32)",com.google.common.io;resolution:=optional;version="[31.1,32)"
 ,com.google.common.math;resolution:=optional;version="[31.1,32)",com.
 google.common.util.concurrent;resolution:=optional;version="[31.1,32)
 ",com.google.gson.stream;resolution:=optional;version="[2.9,3)",com.s
 un.jndi.dns;resolution:=optional,io.grpc;resolution:=optional;version
 ="[1.55,2)",io.grpc.census;resolution:=optional,io.perfmark;resolutio
 n:=optional;version="[0.25,1)",javax.annotation;resolution:=optional,
 javax.naming;resolution:=optional,javax.naming.directory;resolution:=
 optional,javax.net.ssl;resolution:=optional,org.conscrypt;resolution:
 =optional
Require-Capability: osgi.ee;filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"
Tool: Bnd-6.4.0.202211291949
```

Comment: Do the grpc plug-ins export all the necessary packages in the `Export-Package` section of their MANIFEST.MF? Only exported packages can be accessed by other plug-ins.

Comment: I guess no. this is my manifest

Comment: Not your manifest, the manifests of things like the `wrapped.io.grpc.grpc-context` plug-in

Comment: it does, as you can see